# ntpdate timeout ambiguity

Tags: linux, ntp

Does the `ntpdate` option `-t` set the timeout in whole seconds or fractions? The man page isn't entire clear. It says

```
-t  timeout
         Specify the maximum time waiting for a server response as the
         value timeout, in seconds and fraction.  The value is rounded to
         a multiple of 0.2 seconds.  The default is 1 second, a value
         suitable for polling across a LAN.
```

Would `-t 3` be three seconds or .6 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in seconds and fraction

means that you specify the timeout in seconds, but you can add a fraction of a second after the decimal point. You can confirm this by [checking the source code](https://sources.debian.net/src/ntp/1:4.2.6.p5%2Bdfsg-7/ntpdate/ntpdate.c/#L415): the timeout is parsed using [`atolfp`](https://sources.debian.net/src/ntp/1:4.2.6.p5%2Bdfsg-7/libntp/atolfp.c/), which parses numbers into their integer part and fractional part.

> The value is rounded to a multiple of 0.2 seconds

means that the granularity of the timeout is 0.2 seconds. The value is [rounded up](https://sources.debian.net/src/ntp/1:4.2.6.p5%2Bdfsg-7/ntpdate/ntpdate.c/#L421) to the nearest 0.2 seconds (so 3.5 becomes 3.6, but 3.45 becomes 3.4).

So `-t 3` specifies a 3-second timeout.